# Spring Roo & reading property file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo, properties-file

I want to read a simple property file in a Spring Roo project. Seems easy, but having struggled for more than half a day, I need to ask for help.

I read many Q&A on the internet, yet I can not get it to work.
I looked at [Properties with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) and [Spring @PropertySource example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/). 
I'm new to Spring, so please have some patience.

My Spring version is 3.2.8

**Question:**
How can I retrieve to test.name key value in the BaseController class.

I created a very simple Spring Roo application to illustrate what I did.

My Roo script:

```
    // Create a new project
project --topLevelPackage com.springsource.pizzashop --projectName pizzashop

// Setup JPA persistence using EclipseLink and H2
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY

// Create domain entities
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Base
field string --fieldName name --sizeMin 2 --notNull

// Adding web layers
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
```

By default in my "applicationContext.xml":

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
```

I did not change this file. So I did not add a bean.

I added in ..resources\META-INF\spring\ folder the test.properties file, next to the database.properties which lives also there.

```
test.name=Google
test.url=www.google.com
```

I added a Java bean for the configuration file in ...\java\com\springsource\pizzashop\domain\PizzaProperties.java, next to the base.java class file.

```
package com.springsource.pizzashop.domain;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@RooJavaBean
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/test.properties")
public class PizzaProperties {

    @Value("${test.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${test.url}")
    private String url;

}
```

Ofcourse the "PizzaProperties_Roo_JavaBean.aj" is also created having the getters and setter.

The property file is found, because when I change the name to test1.properties, I get an error.

I pushed in the Base.list method to test if I'm able to read the property file. In the method I do a System.out.println.
The result is always:

> In Base.list
>   Name = null

```
package com.springsource.pizzashop.web;
import com.springsource.pizzashop.domain.Base;
import com.springsource.pizzashop.domain.PizzaProperties;

import org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller.scaffold.RooWebScaffold;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RequestMapping("/bases")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "bases", formBackingObject = Base.class)
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {

        System.out.println("In Base.list");
        PizzaProperties config = new PizzaProperties();
        System.out.println("Name = " + config.getName());

        if (page != null || size != null) {
            int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
            final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
            uiModel.addAttribute("bases", Base.findBaseEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
            float nrOfPages = (float) Base.countBases() / sizeNo;
            uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
        } else {
            uiModel.addAttribute("bases", Base.findAllBases(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        }
        return "bases/list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To allow Spring to inject properties must be Spring how creates the Bean.

Try this:

Add to `PizzaProperties` `@Bean` annotation (`@RooJavaBean` just generates *getters* and *setters*)

```
...
...

@RooJavaBean
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/test.properties")
public class PizzaProperties {

...
...
```

Add to `BaseController` a `@Autowired` property for `PizzaProperties`:

```
...
...

@RequestMapping("/bases")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "bases", formBackingObject = Base.class)
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private PizzaProperties config;

    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {


        System.out.println("In Base.list");
        System.out.println("Name = " + config.getName());

...
...
```

Note that all this is just Spring configuration, not special Spring Roo stuff.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

jmvivo certainly set me on the right track.

A little update how I finally managed to read the property file in a Spring Roo project in a very simple, clean way.

1) In the property class only @RooJavaBean and @Component are enough! No need for @PropertySource and also no need to add @Bean.
Probably because of `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>` there is no need to use the @PropertySource annotation.

2) As jmvivo indicates I had to add

`@Autowired
private PizzaProperties config;`

to the class where I want to use the properties.

So in the end it is very clean and simple. I like to keep it KIS.

```
package com.springsource.pizzashop.domain;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@RooJavaBean
@Component
//@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/test.properties")
public class PizzaProperties {

    @Value("${test.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${test.url}")
    private String url;

}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping("/bases")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "bases", formBackingObject = Base.class)
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private PizzaProperties config;

    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {

        System.out.println("In Base.list");
        System.out.println("Name = " + config.getName());

        ...
        ...
```

Again thanks for the help!